# Код на гравитацию не работает Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть игрок `Player`.
Вот его `Inspector`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот его код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform cam;

    public float speed = 6f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;

    Vector3 velocity;

    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    float turnSmoothVelocity;

    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float targetAngel = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngel, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

            Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngel, 0f) * Vector3.forward;

            controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);


        }
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

По идее когда я добавил в код эти 2 строчки:

```
velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
```

Он должен начать падать. Но он не падает.
Код для `Third Person Camera`  и передвижение игрока я взял из этого видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HpC--2iowE

А вот код с гравитацией:

```
velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
```

Я взял из этого видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc

Возможно нужно использовать `controller.Move()` 2 раза, пробовал но не получилось. Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А с каким целями конкретно ты хочешь писать свою реализацию гравитации вместо использования rigitbody?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить:

```
void Start()
{
    velocity = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Возможно поможет, но это не точно